# Detect and replace text paragraph in a markdown document

Tags: javascript, regex, markdown

I am breaking my head trying to write/ use one of the existing markdown parsers to *find and replace* every text paragraph in a markdown document and leave everything else untouched.

Example Input:

```
# A First Level Header

## Second Level Header

Now is the time for all good men to come to the aid of their country. This is just a regular paragraph.

The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog's back.

### Header 3

> This is a blockquote.
> 
> This is the second paragraph in the blockquote.
>
> ## This is an H2 in a blockquote
```

Desired effect is to identify paragraphs and replace them, e.g.

```
# A First Level Header

## Second Level Header

[replaced]

[replaced]

### Header 3

> This is a blockquote.
> 
> This is the second paragraph in the blockquote.
>
> ## This is an H2 in a blockquote
```

Existing libraries such as [`marked`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/marked) or [`markdown-it`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it) appear to be incapable of parsing and re-creating markdown document without side-effects.

What is the best approach to find and replace a text paragraph in a markdown document?

Comment: You should *at least* provide example of input & desired output

Comment: I may rise a conclusion a bit fast but would a markdown paragraph be anything that start with a letter?

Comment: @Thomas I can think of quite a few examples when a paragraph does not start with a character, e.g. https://gist.github.com/gajus/d154559b6a7011d19ae4

Comment: It gets a bit more tricky when lists come into play, e.g. `1. a` and `a. a` indicates a start of a list.

Comment: I didn't even know that you can start a list with `a. something`...

Comment: Your description does not match your example. For example, there are many paragraphs in your example output which have not been replaced. Those paragraphs are nested inside a blockquote. One can also nest paragraphs in lists and other such structures. Or do you want to only replace paragraphs at the root level of the document?

Comment: The latter. "replace paragraphs at the root level of the document". You are right though – I did not consider that these are paragraph tokens, just not at the root level.

Comment: For the record, there is a discussion (inconclusive at the time of writing) about how `markdown-it` can be used to achieve this goal. https://github.com/markdown-it/markdown-it/issues/195

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to list what's not a paragraph...?

Comment: @Thomas That is the approach I am experimenting with at the moment. 

However, the issue I have run into is the block elements, e.g. [GitHub code block](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown/#fenced-code-blocks). I can no longer assume that a beginning of a new line is enough to determine the type of the markdown node – now the parser needs to be context aware.

Comment: @Thomas Here is a regex that implements this approach https://regex101.com/r/nB4rC5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraphs in Markdown are essentially any block of text which is not any other block level construct (as defined by the [Syntax Rules](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax)). So a paragraph is a block of text which is not a header, list, blockquote, codeblock, or horizontal rules (as those are the only other block level constructions defined in Markdown--ignoring some unofficial extensions).

As you are only interested in finding root level paragraphs (not nested ones), a simple approach may be to simply split your document on double line breaks and run a regex against the beginning of each block checking for tokens which identify the non-paragraph types. If it starts with four or more spaces (or one tab); not a paragraph. If it starts with a 0-3 spaces and a hash; not a paragraph. If is starts with 0-3 spaces, a `>` and a space; not a paragraph. If it starts with 0-3 spaces, one of `*, -, +`, and a space, not a paragraph. And so on...

One trouble spot is headers. Headers can only ever be one line, to a hash header may not have a blank line between it and the paragraph following it. However, that is fairly easy to work around as headers can only ever be one line. It you find a header (block that starts with a hash), split off the first line and anything else is a separate block which may or may not be a paragraph.

Of course, a trickier problem is setext headers as the second line identifies them has headers. However a regex that looks for the first newline followed by 3 or more `-` or `=` should do the trick.

If you look at some of the existing Markdown implementations, most of the regex you would need already exists. Of course, you would be developing your own Markdown parser of sorts and various edge cases might sneak through. However, given your very specific needs, I'm not sure you will find an existing parser which will give you what you want.

Comment: "If it starts with 0-3 spaces, one of *, -, +, and a space, not a paragraph." Thats not true. A paragraph can start with an emphasis (e.g. `*foo* bar.`) or a link (e.g. `[foo](..) bar`).

Comment: Yes, but if you have `* foo* bar.` then that is a list item. Notice the space after the first `*`. I covered that scenario by stating that a space must follow the token. And yes, it really is that simple. That is the method the reference implementation uses.

Comment: See an example here: http://johnmacfarlane.net/babelmark2/?normalize=1&text=*foo*+bar.%0A%0A*+foo*+bar.

Comment: Close. A paragraph can have up to three spaces at the beginning and still be a paragraph, but your regex doesn't match that. Also, you should add some lists to your sample document. Consider a multi-line list item. The second line does not need to be indented, but is not a paragraph. however, your regex still matches it.

Answer (score 1):

That's a well known type of problems - source map info required to find source ranges by elements of result. At this moment i don't know markdown parsers with full and correct support of source maps.

But markdown-it and reference commonmark parsers can provide info about source lines (without columns). If you need to do something with root blocks only, then such limited lines info will be enougth. For example, [markdown-it demo](http://markdown-it.github.io/) use lines mapping to srcoll panes in sync.